# List of Interfaces vs. List of Derived Type - Cannot Convert Expression Type to Return Type

Tags: c#, linq, interface

Why does this work:

```
public IList<ICoupon> GetCouponsForSite(string siteSlug)
{
    var coupons = _db.Coupons.Where(x => x.Site.slug == siteSlug)
                     .Select(x => new Coupon(x.id));

    var list = new List<ICoupon>();
    foreach (var coupon in coupons)
    {
        list.Add(coupon);
    }

    return list;
}
```

But this does does not work (error - cannot convert expression type to return type):

```
public IList<ICoupon> GetCouponsForSite(string siteSlug)
{
    return _db.Coupons.Where(x => x.Site.slug == siteSlug)
                      .Select(x => new Coupon(x.id)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because db.Coupons...ToList() returns an `IList<Coupon>` rather than an `IList<ICoupon>`.  `IList<Coupon>` does not derive from `IList<ICoupon>` because C# 3 doesn't support generic variance.  (C# 4 does support generic variance, but it still won't derive in this case.  Consider that whoever receives an `IList<ICoupon>` could try to stuff a SomeEvilTypeThatImplementsICoupon into it.  But an `IList<Coupon>` couldn't accept that because SomeEvilTypeThatImplementsICoupon doesn't derive from Coupon.  See http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2008/12/c-covariance-and-contravariance-by-example.html for discussion of this convertibility issue albeit in a slightly different context, and the Eric Lippert articles linked from there.)

(Your first snippet, by contrast, explicitly constructs a `List<ICoupon>`, which *can* contain anything that implements ICoupon, and then puts some Coupon objects into that list.  Now if the receiver decides to poke SomeEvilTypeThatImplementsICoupon into it, all is well, because the List was built to hold any ICoupon, not just actual Coupon objects.)

Answer (score 4):

It can't implicitly cast List<Coupon> to List<ICoupon>. Try this:

```
public IList<ICoupon> GetCouponsForSite(string siteSlug)
{
    return _db.Coupons.Where(x => x.Site.slug == siteSlug)
                      .Select(x => new Coupon(x.id)).Cast<ICoupon>().ToList();
}
```

The basic reason for this is that if you had for example a `class FancyCoupon : ICoupon` and tried to put that into a `List<Coupon>` then it would fail cause FancyCoupon doesn't derive from Coupon (only ICoupon) but it should work just fine into a `List<ICoupon>`. So while at first glance it looks like it should be able to use one as the other there's rather important differences between the two types.

The cast call essentially iterates over the list and typecasts each one for the new list (There's a bit more to it for performance reasons under the bonnet, but for practical purposes you can think of it that way).

(Updated with fix from comments)

Comment: Typo: _db.Coupons.Where(x => x.Site.slug == siteSlug).Select(x => new Coupon(x.id)).Cast<ICoupon>().ToList() ... but thanks, that works.

Comment: Either of those should work - Cast is on both the IQueryable and the IEnumerable interfaces so you can cast before or after converting to a list. It makes little difference.

Comment: .Cast<>() returns an IEnumerable ... that is why you need to use the .ToList() after the .Cast<>()

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable<ICoupon>` is not derived from `IList<ICoupon>`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Make the return statement `var x = _db...;` then `return x`. Hover over the `var x` to see what type VS thinks it is.

Comment: cannot convert expression type List<Coupon> to return type IList<ICoupon>

Answer (score 0):

This is because the compiler infers `ICoupon`, and not `Coupon`, in the `Select` as generic type argument. So instead of an explicit cast after the `Select` as proposed by others (which not too efficient because it needs to iterate over all items), you can also use implicit casting (or more correctly variance) by specifying the correct [`Select` generic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
public IList<ICoupon> GetCouponsForSite(string siteSlug)
{
    return _db.Coupons.Where(x => x.Site.slug == siteSlug)
                  .Select<?, ICoupon>(x => new Coupon(x.id)).ToList();
}
```

(You need to replace the `?` with the appropriate type of the `Coupons` collection.)